# yahoofinancer for R: Finance API request failed

Tags: r

I get the following message that I did not get previously with the exact same request:

```
Yahoo Finance API request failed
Status: 401
Type: Client error
Mesage: 
Description:  
Error:
```

I tried the following:
reload both R and R studio
load a previous version of R
try with yahoofinancer specific request:

```
glimpse(St_Ticker$quote)                 # ok
St_Ticker$quote$shortName            # ok
St_Ticker$quote$trailingPE           # ok
St_Ticker$quote$forwardPE            # ok
St_Ticker$quote$dividendYield        # ok
glimpse(St_Ticker$financial_data)        # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$get_cash_flow(frequency = "annual", clean_names = TRUE))  # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$get_history())
my_history <- St_Ticker$get_history()
filter(my_history, date >= "2023-07-01")   # ok
glimpse(St_Ticker$grading_history)       # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$index_trend)           # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$key_stats)             # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$price)                 # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$recommendation_trend)  # get failed request
glimpse(St_Ticker$recommendations)       # get data with scores
St_Ticker$recommendations            # ok
St_Ticker$recommendations$symbol     # ok
glimpse(St_Ticker$set_symbol)            # get function (symbol)
glimpse(St_Ticker$summary_detail)        # get failed request
```

I am not well versed enough to play with the URL or perform Web scrapping...
Thanks in advance.
Marc Trudeau

Comment: Hi Marc! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: what is the code to create St_Ticker?

Comment: The code for St_Ticker is the following:   
stocks <-c("IBM", "GOOG", "ENB.TO")

(St_Ticker <- Ticker$new(stocks[2]))
(St_Ticker$set_symbol(stocks[2]))

Comment: I wrote to the designier of the package who answered to me readily that it seems that there is a change in the Yahoo Finance API.  He is working on the issue and will let me know when the problem will be corrected.  I will let you know when this happens.  Thanks.